# SQL ORACLE - Query that show a list how many people is over 50

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having

I'm new (very) in the Oracle sql world

I have a table named ARTISTS with the columns: id_artist, artist_name, born_date, death_date, and also have a table called COUNTRY with the following columns: id_country, country_name

I have to write a query that shows the list of countries and how many artist over 50 have each one, something like this:

COUNTRY | ARTIST OVER 50

JAPAN................35

EEUU.................47

FRANCE............85

I get the age but  I don't  whAt to do for the rest of the query. I was trying to do something with the clausule count, group by and having but I only get error messages like 'missing expression' or problems with group by.

This is what I have

```
SELECT COUNTRY_NAME, COUNT (round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DEATH_DATE,BORN_DATE)/12)),
FROM ARTISTS A JOIN COUNTRY C ON A.COUNTRY=C.ID_COUNTRY
HAVING COUNT (round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DEATH_DATE,BORN_DATE)/12))>50
GROUP BY COUNTRY_NAME
```

I feel very very lost trying to do this query, as I say before, the only thing that I did is the query to know the age of every artist

```
round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DEATH_DATE,BORN_DATE)/12)
```

I hope some of you could help me.

Thanks

Comment: GROUP BY goes before HAVING.

Comment: Remove `,` before `FROM`. and place `group by` before `having`.

Comment: yes now try with @ZunairFatimi's comment

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` before `HAVING` Clause

try this one :

```
SELECT COUNTRY_NAME, COUNT (round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DEATH_DATE,BORN_DATE)/12))
FROM ARTISTS A JOIN COUNTRY C ON A.COUNTRY=C.ID_COUNTRY
GROUP BY COUNTRY_NAME
HAVING COUNT (round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DEATH_DATE,BORN_DATE)/12))>50
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply I tried this and I still have the missing expresion message u__u ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 - "missing expression"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNTRY_NAME, COUNT (round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DEATH_DATE,BORN_DATE)/12))
FROM ARTISTS A JOIN COUNTRY C ON A.COUNTRY=C.ID_COUNTRY
GROUP BY COUNTRY_NAME
HAVING COUNT (round(MONTHS_BETWEEN(DEATH_DATE,BORN_DATE)/12))>50
```

Always use group by before having as you you filter the records after getting the available records....The query execution plan would be, it will first get the records by applying group by and only then apply having clause to filter those results.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply I tried this and I still have the missing expresion message u__u 
    ORA-00936: missing expression
    00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Comment: also remove the comma before **From** as suggested